# Cant add a file to Scrapy Cloud and use it in Settings.py for ScrapyProxies

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I use the MANIFEST.in and i see that file are loaded on the egg folder that its added to Scrapy Cloud. But i keep getting the error.

Here is my Project:
https://dl.dropbox.com/s/b84d2sk8zu8mj34/bases_de_datos.zip

If i run it directly on my PC and it runs perfectly loaded on a file proxylist.txt on the settings.py but once i load it on ScrapyCloud it doesn't work.

Can someone help me on how to do it? i get the error that said

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../proxylist.txt'
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'proxylist.txt'
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/resources/proxylist.txt'
```

i try as much as possible more than 45 trys but it doesnt work.

I would appreciate some guidance.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you checked https://helpdesk.scrapinghub.com/support/solutions/articles/22000200416-deploying-non-code-files ?

Comment: i try the solution but i obtain the result. with  `import pkgutil

PROXY_LIST = pkgutil.get_data("bases_de_datos", "resources/proxylist.txt")`    but no positive  result,  message  is "PROXY_LIST setting is missing"

Comment: i was able to advance in my task with the solution but now it brings all as string. exceptions.IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'http://200.76.236.106:8080\nhttp://189.158.185.148:8080\nhttp://201.173.165.17:8080\nhttp://200.92.152.130:8080\nhttp://189.194.48.14:8080\nhttp://189.201.242.202:8080\nhttp://.....

Comment: What happens if you add a `.splitlines()` at the end of `.get_data(...)`?

Comment: i obtain other error `File "/app/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy_proxies/randomproxy.py", line 35, in __init__
     fin = open(self.proxy_list)        exceptions.TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found`

Comment: [pkgutil.get_data()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data) returns a binary string with the content of the resource (here, a file), not a file pointer. You cannot use `open()` on a string unless you use `StringIO` or `BytesIO`. So you can try `fin = io.BytesIO(pkgutil.get_data("bases_de_datos", "resources/proxylist.txt"))`. You have not shared `rand‌​omproxy.py` so it's hard to help you further.

Comment: since its a module for python i cant add it directly, here is the link [randomproxy.py](https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies/blob/master/scrapy_proxies/randomproxy.py). i will try to ioBytesIO in the afternoon. since i dont have a way to change the randomproxy.py content in scrapycloud i dont think i have a way to use it. i may need to change but use it as a custom proxy. i would preffer to use this already build solution but i think  i cant.

Comment: See my answer on how to get the file path to a package resource so that you can use it with `scrapy-proxies` in `PROXY_LIST`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sample Scrapy project, called "fileresource", that I deployed on Scrapy Cloud and using a local file as package resource.

```
$ tree
.
├── fileresource
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── middlewares.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── resources
│   │   └── mylist.txt
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── spiders
│       ├── example.py
│       └── __init__.py
├── requirements.txt
├── scrapinghub.yml
├── scrapy.cfg
└── setup.py
```

My sample file with list of proxies (fake, only for testing):

```
$ cat fileresource/resources/mylist.txt 
http://localhost:45793
http://localhost:45794
http://localhost:45795
```

And this is an example `settings.py`, with a `PROXY_LIST` setting resolving the resource file path using `sys` and `os`:

```
$ cat fileresource/settings.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys


BOT_NAME = 'fileresource'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['fileresource.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'fileresource.spiders'

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 90,
    'scrapy_proxies.RandomProxy': 100,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
}

PROXY_LIST = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.modules['fileresource'].__file__),
    'resources/mylist.txt')
```

The `setup.py` is very much like [the example in Scrapinghub's knowledge base](https://helpdesk.scrapinghub.com/support/solutions/articles/22000200416-deploying-non-code-files):

```
$ cat setup.py 
# Automatically created by: shub deploy

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name         = 'fileresource',
    version      = '1.0',
    packages     = find_packages(),
    package_data={
        'fileresource': ['resources/*.txt']
    },
    entry_points = {'scrapy': ['settings = fileresource.settings']},
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

I tested it with a `requirements.txt` file having `scrapy-proxies`:

```
$ cat requirements.txt 
scrapy-proxies

$ cat scrapinghub.yml 
project: 123456789
requirements:
  file: requirements.txt
```

Comment: There is no need to add PROXY_LIST into settings